# Jupyter Lab not working: the cell runs forever and python is not detected

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, jupyter-lab

Jupyter Lab is not working.

I open the terminal from a Mac and run:

> MBPdiAlessandro:~ alessandro$ jupyter-lab

Then Jupyter opens through Safari.
I close all the active kernels.
I make a new Python 3 (ipykernel) Notebook.
I make sure the Python kernel is selected.

I write

```
print('hello')
```

and run the cell. The cell runs forever and also the code is not coloured, as you can see in the attached picture.

[image]

The only logs that I get from the terminal where I run jupyter are:

> [I 2023-12-01 16:33:16.027 ServerApp] Kernel started: 11e9e96c-dd23-49c4-8512-e5b740b00cb2
>
> [I 2023-12-01 16:33:17.711 ServerApp] Connecting to kernel 11e9e96c-dd23-49c4-8512-e5b740b00cb2.

I have to idea what is going on. Until some days ago it was working fine.

Let me know any other kind of information you may need.